# Nicest way to check if a value crosses a threshold within a time frame

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas Dataframe from csv looking like this:

```
DATE,DESCRIPTION,SELL,BUY:
2014-01-16 15:25:57.817728,"text1",7,10
2014-01-16 15:26:01.445759,"text2",5,8
2014-01-16 15:26:57.856787,"text3",4,10
...
```

What would be the nicest way to check if a value in the BUY column crosses below a certain threshold within a given time frame, say, for the sake of example, between .minute 40 and .minute 50 and then return the row number ? (only if a cross happens, not if if value is already below a certain threshold befor the given time)

Comment: Not sure how to answer this if the csv doesn't include actual dates... :s

Comment: @AndyHayden I've edited the question with more accurate information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your rows are sorted in increasing time order, like in your example (and 'DATE' is a data column not index), then here's one way to achieve what you want:

To cross below a `THRESHOLD` at row t means that `BUY < threshold` at t and `BUY >= THRESHOLD` at t-1. Suppose that `D` is your dataframe, this is achieved by condition:

`cond = (D['BUY'] < threshold) & (D['BUY'].shift(1) >= threshold)`.

To get all crossing time row indices between `START_TIME` and `END_TIME`:

`d = D[cond]`

`cross_row_inds = d[(d['DATE'] >= START_TIME) & (d['DATE'] <= END_TIME)].index`

You could also select time first, which might be slightly faster if `DATE` was a sorted datetime index instead of a data column. But there, depending on your semantics, you might need to include one time instance right before the START_TIME.

Comment: Trying this now. DATE is a sorted datetime index in my case .

Comment: the condition seems to work, I just have a problem when calling date, since the columns is interpreted as a datetime index, it errors out this way : "KeyError : 'no item named DATE' . Is there a way it could call the .minute from the datetime index instead ? ( My data only contains data for a duration less than an hour)

Comment: if date is an index, then you could actually use call select on it, with sth like d.select(lambda x: x.minute <some condition here>). check the doc for details

Answer (score 0):

This may be irrelevant for your situation, but I also was trying to figure out how to return True when a price crosses a threshold. In my case, I was trying to figure out how to return True any time the price of Bitcoin crossed the next $1,000 mark. This is what I came up with.

```
import math

rate = price() #fetches the price of bitcoin

def round_to_lowest_thousand(number):
    return 1000*math.floor(number/1000)

def cross_threshold():
    global rate
    sleep(2)
    rate2 = price()
    if round_to_thousand(rate) != round_to_thousand(rate2):
        return True 
        rate = rate2
    else:
        rate = rate2

cross_threshold()
```

Hopefully this helps